# onSelect callback on Mobiscroll Datepicker

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

In one of my projects i am using Jquery mobile and Mobiscroll 2.0 (as datetime picker)
I use a generic callback on all Scrollers to get a call when a value is set.

```
$('.input-datetime').scroller({preset: 'datetime',
     mode: 'scroller',
     onSelect: __datetimeOnSelectDelegate});
```

now in the function below, I would like to check and see which "input" element's value is being set?

```
function __datetimeOnSelectDelegate(textDate, inst) { 
         if ($(inst).attr("id") == "StartDate") {
           //Do something
         }
}
```

The above statement won't work!

Would you be able to show me how i can access the Id of the input element on which the Scroller is hooked on?

Comment: I would need to also mention that the jQuery UI Datepicker works this way, the inst paramter is in fact the input element.

Comment: I have to disagree, jQuery UI Datepicker works exact the same way, this refers to the input element, while inst refers to the Datepicker object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "inst" is the mobiscroll object. The HTML object is "this".
Use

```
if (this.id == "StartDate") {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Tried this.id the value is "undefined". Any other ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dioslaska/g83YE/53/ I guess you are not using 2.0, prior to that 'this' referred to the settings object, that's why this.id was undefined

Comment: yes I am using version 2.0! What should I do?
The file name is: mobiscroll-2.0.custom.min.js

Comment: Is the jsfiddle working for you? If yes, create a new one with your code which is not working.

Comment: you were right. I have two wrapper methods and the "this" reference was getting lost between the two method calls.